# Web Server Programming

Tags: python, ios, database

All, this question may be broad; very broad. I've been trying to answer this over a very long time now but it usually ends up being unanswered and I move on to doing my usual work.

Assume a situation where I have an iOS app that needs to:

1. Store & Retrieve User Information &
2. Send some actions from the phone to do some cloud processing

I am highly experienced in iOS & C Programming. As for scripting, I'm good in Python & Perl. But the issue is, I can't seem to understand how to proceed.

Specific questions that I need to be answered:

1. How to do efficient and scalable server-programming? I am a pro-Python guy and I really don't like to fiddle around PHP.
2. How would this set up look like?

Can somebody point to some great examples as to how to set up all of this?

A beginners intro would be good enough at this point.

EDIT: I've seen questions where people have looked for tutorials, books, guides, etc. But it turned out, they were closed. The question is too broad and not meaningful for stackoverflow. This shall be pruned or deleted. Apologies.

Comment: Too broad, but here is a site that has lots of good information: http://highscalability.com/

Comment: This is way too broad and it is two questions in one. Not to mention, people are unlikely to answer anything you post unless you accept some answers on previous questions.

Comment: @Lattyware, I understand that it's broad and there are multiple questions in one. But what do I've to do to get an answer. Make stackoverflow++ so people could ask general questions as well? I could've tried to make this a single question but I need to get started onto something.

Comment: @omniDETH A site like that wouldn't suit the format of the stackoverflow site - and the format is what makes it so useful. What you need to do is research it yourself, and try and implement it. When you reach a specific problem in that implementation, come back for help.

Comment: I seem to agree with that and I guess, I've been served well. I've been banned from asking questions. Is there a code of conduct document that I can read and try to get my account back? Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, I've read all that I could and patiently wait to see if my stars shine. Thank you all, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to how to do scalable server programming is to split the problem into pieces. If it involves data storage, then you need a scalable database. If it involves a web front end, you need a scalable web server farm. You'll probably need load balancing in front of it.

With the front end and back end assembled from off the shelf parts, all that's left for you is the creamy center. You can certainly do that with PHP scripts, since you have multiple web servers to run them and a scalable database behind them.